# HttpWebrequest Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused

Tags: soap, httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-3.1, webrequest, .net-core-3.1

I'm getting Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused while using soap request.

```
 var credentials = new NetworkCredential();
 HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
 (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_configuration.GetSection("RxConfig:Url").Value);
```

The same code is working in .netcore 2.1. This issue occured after I migrated to .net core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to answer.

```
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
```

Once I used keepalive=true the error is gone.

Hope this answer helps someone looking for answer.